# align a link under a center aligned div element

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, alignment

Im trying to align a link,

```
<a class='dotted' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='bottom' data-content='This server is hadnling everyones logins, if this server is down, you couldnt log in to Minecraft.' title='Logins server'>What does this do?</a>
```

under a div element wich has these style properties:

```
.service {
    width:140px;
    height:100px;
    padding:1.2em 0;
    margin:0 0 .5em 0;
    border:3px solid#00AFED;
    border-radius:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    display: inline;
}
```

The problem is that this div repeats itself a few time, and is center aligned, and i need the link aligned directly under each of these div elements, iv'e searched for it for some time in the internet but haven't found anything that works, so any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Why does the CSS you posted have two display rules?

Comment: oh, oops, a typo, there supposed to be a * before on of the display elements, thanks

Comment: can you show use a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9td2/

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/EBDg5/

Answer (score 0):

do you wont somemthing like that : http://jsfiddle.net/Y7n2f/

```
  a.dotted {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    color: #0088cc;
    cursor: help;
    position: relative;
    left: -130px;
    top: 80px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me well, hope it will resolve your issue.

add this class in css:

```
.wrap_link{ text-align:center;}
.dotted{ display:block;}
```

**Try to add link in this structure**

```
<div class="wrap_link">
<div class="service">
content/text
</div>
<a class='dotted' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='bottom' data-content='This server is hadnling everyones logins, if this server is down, you couldnt log in to Minecraft.' title='Logins server'>What does this do?</a>
</div>
```